# How to add 2 words from an array to a string from another array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am writing a mad lib program for school. The program must have 30 sentences, with two words from each sentence missing. I planned to store the sentences in an array, user-inputted words in a second array, and then add words from the word array to the sentences in the sentence array. When using for loops to do this, it works for the first sentence, but in every sentence after that the the same words are used.

Here's the code I have for this part:

```
String story[] = {"Once upon a time, there was a _ man named _.", "He loved playing _ on _ afternoons."};

String words[] = {"awesome", "James", "checkers", "Sunday"};

for (int i = 0; i < story.length; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) { 
        story[i] = story[i].replaceFirst(placeholder, words[j]); // placeholder is set to '_'
    }
System.out.println(story[i]); 
}
```

Comment: That happens, because in your looping logic, you can see that after in each iteration, you reset the value of `j` to 0. I can help you with the solution, but I can't see a expected output in the question so this is all that I can provide.

Comment: move the `int j=0` between two for loops

Comment: Thank you Samridh!!! It's always the simplest things that slip my mind in the frustrating moments. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

This would work if you really solve it with this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < story.length; i++) { 
    for (int j = i*2; j < (i*2)+1; j++) { 
        story[i] = story[i].replaceFirst(placeholder, words[j]); // placeholder is set to '_'
    }
    System.out.println(story[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    String story[] = {"Once upon a time, there was a _ man named _.", "He loved playing _ on _ afternoons."};
    String words[] = {"awesome", "James", "checkers", "Sunday"};
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < story.length; i++) {
        while(story[i].contains("_")){
            story[i] = story[i].replaceFirst("_", words[j++]);
        }
        System.out.println(story[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to your case the `words` array will contain x2 elements more than `story` array. We can use that to write a simple algorithm:

```
String story[] = {"Once upon a time, there was a _ man named _.", "He loved playing _ on _ afternoons."};
String words[] = {"awesome", "James", "checkers", "Sunday"};
String placeholder = "_";
for (int i = 0; i < story.length; i++) {
    String word1 = words[i * 2];
    String word2 = words[i * 2 + 1];
    story[i] = story[i]
            .replaceFirst(placeholder, word1)
            .replaceFirst(placeholder, word2);

    System.out.println(story[i]);
}
```